# Chef notification within each method

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, devops

I have a recipe that iterates a hash containing SQL scripts in an `each` method and -- in case the script changed from the previous run -- the `cookbook_file` resource notifies the `execute` resource to run.
The issue is that it seems it always runs the `execute` using the last element of the hash.

Following the attributes file

```
default['sql_scripts_dir'] = 'C:\\DBScripts'
default['script_runner']['scripts'] = [
    { 'name' => 'test', 'hostname' => 'local' },
    { 'name' => 'test2', 'hostname' => 'local' },
    { 'name' => 'test3', 'hostname' => 'local' },
    { 'name' => 'test4', 'hostname' => 'local' },
]
```

And the recipe

```
directory node['sql_scripts_dir'] do
  recursive true
end

node['script_runner']['scripts'].each do |script|
    cookbook_file "#{node['sql_scripts_dir']}\\#{script['name']}.sql" do
      source "#{script['name']}.sql"
      action :create
      notifies :run, 'execute[Create_scripts]', :immediately
    end
  
    execute 'Create_scripts' do
      command "sqlcmd -S \"#{script['hostname']}\" -i \"#{node['sql_scripts_dir']}\\#{script['name']}.sql\""
      action :nothing
    end
end
```

And it produces the following output:

```
Recipe: test_runner::default
         * directory[C:\DBScripts] action create
           - create new directory C:\DBScripts
         * cookbook_file[C:\DBScripts\test.sql] action create
           - create new file C:\DBScripts\test.sql
           - update content in file C:\DBScripts\test.sql from none to 8c40f1
           --- C:\DBScripts\test.sql    2020-07-30 17:30:30.959220400 +0000
           +++ C:\DBScripts/chef-test20200730-1500-11bz3an.sql  2020-07-30 17:30:30.959220400 +0000
           @@ -1 +1,2 @@
           +select @@version
         * execute[Create_scripts] action run

           ================================================================================
           Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[Create_scripts]'
           ================================================================================

           Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
           ------------------------------------
           Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
           ---- Begin output of sqlcmd -S "local" -i "C:\DBScripts\test4.sql" ----
           STDOUT:
           STDERR: Sqlcmd: 'C:\DBScripts\test4.sql': Invalid filename.
           ---- End output of sqlcmd -S "local" -i "C:\DBScripts\test4.sql" ----
           Ran sqlcmd -S "local" -i "C:\DBScripts\test4.sql" returned 1
```

The expected behavior is that the recipe runs sequentially the 4 scripts in the example instead of running just the last one. What am I missing for getting it done?

Comment: You are building a resource collection with 4 cookbook_file resources and 4 nearly identical resources all named `execute[Create_scripts]`, when the notification fires it always finds the last one, so it runs against `test4`.  You need something like `execute "create #{script['name']} scripts"` and similarly change the notification.

Comment: good point, will try

Comment: works like a charm, @lamont please convert it to be an answer so I can accept it. thx

Comment: okay, wrote something down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating 4 nearly identical resources all named `execute[Create_scripts]` and when the notification fires from the first `cookbook_file` resource being updated it finds the *last* one of them to be notified and runs against `test4` (no matter which cookbook_file resource updates).

The fix is to use string interpolation to change the name of the execute resources to be unique and to notify based on that unique name:

```
directory node['sql_scripts_dir'] do
  recursive true
end

node['script_runner']['scripts'].each do |script|
    cookbook_file "#{node['sql_scripts_dir']}\\#{script['name']}.sql" do
      source "#{script['name']}.sql"
      action :create
      notifies :run, "execute[create #{script['name']} scripts]", :immediately
    end

    execute "create #{script['name']} scripts" do
      command "sqlcmd -S \"#{script['hostname']}\" -i \"#{node['sql_scripts_dir']}\\#{script['name']}.sql\""
      action :nothing
    end
end
```

Note that this is a manifestation of the same issues behind the old CHEF-3694 warning message where what would happen is that all the four execute resources would be merged into one resource via "resource cloning" with the properties of the subsequent resource being "last-writer-wins".

In Chef 13 this was changed to remove resource cloning and the warning, and in most circumstances having two resources named the same thing in the resource collection is totally harmless -- until you try to notify one of those resources.  The resource notification system should really warn in this situation rather than silently picking the last resource that matches (but between notifications, subscribes, lazy resolution and now unified_mode that code is very complicated and you only want it to be firing under exactly the right conditions).